# Using X11 over the network to get more screens

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager

I have two machines each of which can drive two displays, and I'm trying to figure out how to configure X so that I have 4 X screens all managed by the same window manager.  I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Stumpwm on both of the boxes, but I'd be fine with changing to another distro or window manager if it makes things easier.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dmx](http://dmx.sourceforge.net/)!  `Xdmx` provides a single X server which, rather than attaching to hardware, attaches to multiple *other* X servers, and provides a display which spans all of them.